# Android- the DDMS shows the message: logcat read: Invalid argument

Tags: android, ddms

So how can I fix this problem. It seems my DDMS is broken down.

Answer (score 13):

It really helped by plugging in/unplugging the device, followed by the command '`adb logcat -c`'

Answer (score 7):

In my case the log stopped every time i uploaded a new version of my app to the phone.

issuing the command "adb logcat -c" followed by unplug/plug worked fine.

Thx for the hints.

Answer (score 1):

Is it a real device, or the emulator?

If you're getting that from a phone, logging might be disabled. try this in `adb shell`:

```
echo 1 > /sys/kernel/logger/log_main/enable
echo 2 > /sys/kernel/logger/log_main/priority
```

But, if you're getting that after a while (some logs get printed, then it stops), try:

```
adb logcat -c
```

Answer (score 1):

Should be one kinda bug in android plugins.

Restarted the 
a. ADB server(adb kill-server, adb start-server) , 
b. eclipse and 
c. re-connected the device (real phone) .

This helped me to get DDMS Logcat back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem,

Now i can fix it.

Go to DDMS, click on the name of device or Emulator  (on the left top Window)

and logcat will show :)